# Web Crawler with JavaScript support in Perl?

Tags: javascript, html, perl, browser

I want to code a **perl** application that would **crawl** some websites and collect **images** and **links** from such webpages. Because the most of pages use **JavaScript** that generate a **HTML** content, I need to code quasi a client browser with JavaScript support to be able to **parse** a final HTML code that is generated and/or modified by JavaScript. What are my options?

If possible, please publish some implementation code or link to some example(s).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I handle Javascript in a Perl web crawler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769015/how-can-i-handle-javascript-in-a-perl-web-crawler)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several options.

- [Win32::IE::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aIE%3a%3aMechanize) on Windows
- [Mozilla::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/Mozilla%3a%3aMechanize)
- [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)
- [WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aSelenium)
- [Wight](https://metacpan.org/pod/Wight)

Comment: "What are my options?" was the question.  A list of modules seems like a good list of options.

Comment: It's Perl. The documentation for modules tends to have code in it.

Answer (score 6):

Options that spring to mind:

- You could have [Perl use Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/~lukec/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.32/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm) and have a full-blown browser do the work for you.
- You can download and compile [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) or another open source JavaScript engine and have Perl call an external program to evaluate the JavaScript.
- I don't think Perl's [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP.pm) module supports JavaScript, but you might want to check that if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 6):

[WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Scripter) with the [WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Scripter-Plugin-JavaScript) and [WWW::Scripter::Plugin::Ajax](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Scripter-Plugin-Ajax) plugins seems like the closest you'll get without using an actual browser (the modules [WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Selenium), [Mozilla::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mozilla-Mechanize) or [Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-IE-Mechanize) use real browsers).

Comment: is any module like WWW::Scripter support with V8 engine?

Answer (score 3):

Check the complete working example featured in the [Scraping pages full of JavaScript](http://showmetheco.de/articles/2012/11/scraping-pages-full-of-javascript.html). It uses [Web::Scraper](http://cpan.me/Web%3a%3aScraper) for HTML processing and [Gtk3::WebKit](http://cpan.me/Gtk3%3a%3aWebKit) to process dynamic content. However, the later one is quite a PITA to install. If there are not-that-many pages you need to scrape (< 1000), fetching the post-processed DOM content through [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is an interesting option. I've written the following script for that purpose:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    address, output;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: phantomjs --load-images=no html.js URL filename');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        } else {
            fs.write(output, page.content, 'w');
        }
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

There's something like that on the CPAN already, it's a module called [Wight](http://cpan.me/Wight), but I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score -1):

WWW::Mechanize::Firefox can use with mozrepl, with all javascript action.