# Getting error in accessing a link using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, mechanize

Getting the following error in a JavaScript link using perl - [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm).

> Error GETing javascript:submt_os('2','contact%20info','contact%20info'):Protocol scheme 'javascript' is not supported

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$uri="http://tinyurl.com/76xv4ld";
$mech->get($uri);

# error on this link
$mech->follow_link( text => 'Contact Information');

print $mech->content();
```

Once I get the page, I want to click *Contact Information*.

Is there any other way to click *Contact Information*?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769015/how-can-i-handle-javascript-in-a-perl-web-crawler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559927/web-crawler-with-javascript-support-in-perl - It helps to search Stack Overflow and the Web with the relevant keywords before asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't follow a javascript link with WWW::Mechanize. Even if you had a javascript interpreter you'd need complete DOM support for anything non-trivial.

So - you need to script a web-browser. I use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) in my testing, which is quite bulky and requires java. You might want to investigate [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox/). I've not used it but it does provide a mechanize style interface to Firefox.