# Working interactively with WebExtensions in Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a page which leads to other pages that loads mp3 files. I want to download them. All pages and links are build dynamically.

In a past I used Scratchpad but now it is deprecated and new API is here [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

I can't call `browser.tabs.create` from console. How can I interactively use WebExtensions in Firefox?

Comment: I found t is much easy to go with: * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345623/scraping-dynamic-content-using-python-scrapy
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559927/web-crawler-with-javascript-support-in-perl

Answer (score 1):

The code that used to be run from the *Scratchpad* can still be run from the *[Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)*. The *Browser Console* can be open from the *Web Developer* menu or using **Ctrl+Shift+J**.